# Singular-value of $f$(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I try to prove below question but I did not succeed.

The question asked to prove this:

> If A is symmetric and σ is a singular-value of A, then for each odd or
>   even function like $f$(A), |$f$(σ)| is a singular value of $f$(A).

Can you help me to prove it, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Thanks for your reply. I know, if A is symmetric its singular-value is also its eigenvalue. So I tried to prove that eigenvalue of f(A) is |f(σ)|. ‌But I can't find any solution to find eigenvalue of f(A). Can you help me ?

Comment: What is the definition of $f(A)$ ?

Comment: @Youem Any even/odd functions like A^2 or Cos(A) or ...

Comment: But how would you define $\cos (A)$ for matrix $A$.